# resize hard disk for live sistem ext4

Tags: linux, partition, fdisk

I have an Ubuntu 16.10 virtual server, upon reinstall I got:

```
root@ip140:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       5.5G  1.6G  3.7G  30% /
```

`fdisk -l`

```
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 11718655 11716608  5.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       11718656 12580863   862208  421M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       12580864 41942975 29362112   14G 83 Linux
```

I did try a lot of things to fdisk /dev/sda delete 1 delete 3 and make a new one, however because the swap is the partition no 2, the system won't resize my partition, and I cannot do a live rescue. The only way I can do is using the ssh. How can I delete 1 and 3 and combine them all together? Or how can I delete them all 3 and make 1 / full size and additional 200MB swap without damage the actual system?

Comment: Since it's the boot drive the kernel probably won't reload the partition table until to reboot unless you run a particular `partprobe` command to force it to reload all partition tables but that command could be dangerous if your system is particularly I/O bound.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `/dev/sda3` is not essential for the system to boot or for you to login via SSH. Double check to make sure. If this is the case, then

1. Turn off swap, thus making it possible to delete `/dev/sda2`:

   ```
   sudo swapoff -a
   ```
2. Comment out the line in `/etc/fstab` mounting `/dev/sda2` as a swap partition. (Probably it is called out by UUID, not by the device name.)
3. If `/dev/sda3` is mounted, umount it; make sure `/dev/sda3` is not mounted in `/etc/fstab`.
4. Delete partitions 2 and 3, extend partition 1 and make a new partition 2:

   ```
   sudo parted /dev/sda -- rm 3
   sudo parted /dev/sda -- rm 2
   sudo parted /dev/sda -- unit s resizepart 1 41080767
   sudo parted /dev/sda -- unit s mkpart primary linux-swap 41080767 -1
   ```
5. Reboot.
6. Connect to the system again.
7. Format `/dev/sda2` for swap and enable swap:

   ```
    sudo mkswap /dev/sda2
    sudo swapon /dev/sda2
   ```
8. Extend the file system on `/dev/sda1`:

   ```
    sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
   ```
9. Get the new UUID of `/dev/sda2` from `lsblk` and update `/etc/fstab` accordingly.
10. That's all.

---

The OP replied:

Did that,

the result is the same

```
 root@ip140:~# resize2fs /dev/sda1
 resize2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
 The filesystem is already 1464576 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

 # df -h
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            979M     0  979M   0% /dev
 tmpfs           200M  3.2M  197M   2% /run
 /dev/sda1       5.5G  1.9G  3.4G  36% /
 tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/0
 root@ip140:~#
```

Comment: did the way you said: the result is: root@ip140:~# resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
The filesystem is already 1464576 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

root@ip140:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            979M     0  979M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  3.2M  197M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       5.5G  1.9G  3.4G  36% /
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/0
root@ip140:~#

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete swap partition, you have to turn off swapping:

```
swapoff /dev/sda2
```

After that, you can try to delete the second partition.

But be careful: you have to set beginning of the first partition exactly to the place, where is beginning now, otherwise mount of this partition will fail - mount will not find superblock of this partition.

If you are not absolutely sure, what you are doing, don't do it - it is very risky operation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I did work after I manage to run the fdisk on /dev/sda
delete partition
re-add partitional
resize using resize2fs